# Как правильно обрабатывать нескольких пользователей telegram bot c#

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, telegram, .net-core

Пишу простенького telegram бота на C#. По команде "/start" бот приветствует юзера и предлагает пройти тест. После чего пользователь должен нажать кнопку "начать тест". При прохождении теста несколькими пользователями программа ломается, так как я храню в поле Psycho.ChatIdOfTestSubject идентификатор чата пользователя, который нажал /start. Как сделать правильную обработку нескольких пользователей, чтобы логика бота работала для каждого пользователя независимо. Можно ли это сделать без базы данных?

```
private static async Task HandleMessage(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
                
            if (message.Text == "/start")
            {
                Psycho.ChatIdOfTestSubject = message.Chat.Id;
                Psycho.FirstNameOfTestSubject = message.Chat.FirstName;
                Psycho.MessageId = message.MessageId;
                            
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(Psycho.ChatIdOfTestSubject, $"Привет, {Psycho.FirstNameOfTestSubject}!\r\nЯ бот, с помощью которого можно узнать свой соционический тип. Начнем?", replyMarkup:Psycho.CreateStartKeyboard());
                
                return;
    
            }
}
```

Comment: База данных нужна чтобы хранить историю диалога и остальные данные отдельно для каждого пользователя, и основываясь на них писать новые сообщения. База данных может быть в виде простого json-файла, если вы не хотите (почему?) настоящую

Comment: Пользователь запускает тест, 
и другой пользователь начнёт тест, и зайдёт новый пользователь и начнёт тест, как мне обрабатывать их ответы и вести тест для них независимо друг от друга, чтобы тест был уникальным для каждого? Не знаю как выстроить такую архитектуру. На счёт базы: ответ - невежество. Пока что я не владею базами, а хотелось бы выстроить логику, чтобы хотя бы пара тройка пользователей могли параллельно пользоваться ботом.

Comment: нужно для каждого пользователя хранить данные отдельно, сделайте минимально класс `UserData` со всеми нужными данными для одного пользователя, затем сделайте список таких классов. При загрузке программы бота - загружайте список из json-файла, а перед выключением - сохраняйте список в файл. Если добавляется человек, id чата которого нет ни у одного объекта из списка, добавляйте новый элемент в список. При каждом сообщении изменяйте и проверяйте настройки объекта с нужным значением id чата, полученных из данных сообщения. Вот вам мини база данных, для которой не нужно сильно много умений.

Comment: [Сериализация в JSON](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php)

Comment: Я как раз сделал такой класс, но не знал, как его правильно применить. Спасибо большое за подсказку. Буду реализовывать!